# MapView with firebase Android

Tags: java, android

I've had a problem for a very long time.  Nowhere could I find an answer to this question.  It's about MapView.  I wanted to create an application using firebase.  In firebase I wanted to store the position and name of the tags from the map, but I don't know how to make it work.  I want the user ID to be a marker ID so that all logged in users can see on the map.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by following trick

- Create a collection storing user ID, LatLng points
- Query them in the MapView class and add the markers at that latlng points.

Code for adding a marker goes something like this

```
LatLng sydney = new LatLng(-33.852, 151.211);
        googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
            .position(sydney)
            .title("Marker in Sydney"));
        googleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(sydney));
```

You can use the firebase geopoint datatype to save the latlng point in firestore.